# Losing track of shnayim mikra progress

Tags: shnayim-mikra

I had a paper that kept track which parashiot for which I did not yet learn shnayim mikrah this year.

Then I misplaced it.

Is there any official advice regarding what to do in that situation, or is the only option to learn all the parashiot until the parasha of the week one misplaces his note, or excluding the weeks he is certain he did indeed learn those weeks.

Comment: It sounds like you still have your chumash handy. Try marking it in there.

Comment: This question would generally only occur based on a practice of not reading all of them in order, a practice many early authorities wouldn't have thought to deal with.

Comment: @DoubleAA Then would reading previous parashiot after the current ones not qualify for shnayim mikrah? or qualify according to any of them?

Comment: @Yaakov Most opinions permit קריאת התורה למפרע post facto, unlike Megillat Esther.